# Synonymize [paginate] and [pagination]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

Questions with these tags mostly overlap, there doesn't seem to be any difference between them. Unless there is a reason for both tags to exist that I miss, please make [paginate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paginate) a synonym of [pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagination).

Comment: The oldest question that is tagged with 'paginate' is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1900572/2821954) (2009), which I don't see why it needs a different tag than ['pagination' since 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10190/2821954).

Comment: Do we need a tag for this? How about if we remove both?

Comment: @Braiam Because it is actually a useful tag. It can be related to implementation of pagination logic/algorithm or something like this

Comment: @Braiam you can create a burnination request if you want. But I'd vote against it.
here is the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67689667/qlik-rest-connector-how-to-retrieve-all-paginated-data-by-calling-an-api-as-to) of post that uses [tag:pagination] tag correctly - question is related to pagination in Qlik

Comment: @VadimKotov are you sure that that is a good example? It uses other problematic tag (api) and one that has nothing to do (xml) while the important one (quiksense) is relegated to the last position, which is arguably the main topic of the question: "how to do X with quicksense?"